# ODSEE 11.1.1.7 pagination support

Tags: ldap, oracle, directory-services

I installed Oracle Directory Services Enterprise Edition 11.1.1.7 and it by default does not support pagination critical extension. I searched in the web and
found that ODSEE 5.2 has not been supported it (by default or by any configuraiton).

My question is whether ODSEE 11.1.1.7 has any option to enable pagination support?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know ODSEE doesn't support [RFC 2696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2696) (simple paged results control / OID 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319), which isn't a critical extension. It is really not the same thing, but ODSEE [supports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29127_01/doc.111170/e28972/ds-indexing.htm#bcaug) the [Virtual List View (VLV) extension](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ldapext-ldapv3-vlv-09), which perhaps might still be useful to what you're trying to do. Please note that none of these controls/extensions are part of the protocol and directory service doesn't have to implement them. Marking a control critical not supported by DSA will only cause it to fail the operation (e.g., LDAP search).